# Fetch data from API in Svelte

Tags: api, svelte

I am new to Svelte and I am trying to fetch some data from an API.

The code snippet is shown below:

```
//LatestBook.svelte
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";


    let api='http://lumen';
    let uri=api+'/books';
    let book=[];

    onMount(async () => {
        const res=await fetch(uri);
        const data= await res.json();
        book=data;
        console.log(book);
        console.log(book.bc);
        
    });

</script>
```

The first `console.log(book)` shows the following:

```
Object { data: {…} }
data: Object { bc: 1991, wc: "516208", pc: "775886", … }
bc: 1991
pc: "775886"
vc: 1930409
wc: "516208"
```

So I am sure the API succeded. But the 2nd `console.log(book.bc)` says `undefined`.

What went wrong here?
​​
: Object { … }
​

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I have figured out what happened: the returned data here has another `data` field, so I need to somehow use `book=data.data` and then it works.

Now an additional question: though the component loads correctly, there are some nasty error messages in my VSC window:

```
[{
    "resource": "/d:/vagrant_env/rsywx/ss/src/lib/layout/widget/LatestBook.svelte",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": "7005",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Variable 'book' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.",

}]
```

The above message shows for every property that I am trying to get from the `book` variable.

Please advise. Thanks.